# fsunit.xunit test exception in constructor

Tags: f#, xunit, fsunit, guard-clause

Having

```
type Category(name : string, categoryType : CategoryType) = 
        do
            if (name.Length = 0) then
                invalidArg "name" "name is empty"
```

i'm trying to test this exception using FsUnit + xUnit:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``name should not be empty``() =
    (fun () -> Category(String.Empty, CategoryType.Terminal)) |> should throw typeof<ArgumentException>
```

but when it runs I see [XUnit.MatchException](http://take.ms/oiY18).
What i'm doing wrong?

1. [Test source code](https://github.com/dimamartovoi/ugp/blob/master/Tests/UGP.Core.Tests/CategoryTests.fs)
2. [Category type source code](https://github.com/dimamartovoi/ugp/blob/master/UGP.Core/Category.fs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm not an FsUnit expert, I think the `MatchException` type is expected, because FsUnit uses custom matchers, and the match doesn't succeed.

However, the test, as written, seems to be incorrect, because

```
(fun () -> Category(String.Empty, CategoryType.Terminal)
```

is a function with the signature `unit -> Category`, but you don't really care about the returned `Category`.

Instead, you can write it as

```
[<Fact>]
let ``name should not be empty``() =
    (fun () -> Category(String.Empty, CategoryType.Terminal) |> ignore)
    |> should throw typeof<ArgumentException>
```

Notice the added `ignore` keyword, which ignores the `Category` return value. This test passes, and fails if you remove the Guard Clause.

Comment: https://github.com/fsprojects/FsUnit/issues/14 If you download the source code and build it on windows, some unit tests surrounding exception testing fail. I'm just learning F# so I can't resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh, dear, thanks for the link... I'm pretty sure the above code worked when I tried it, and I'm running Windows as well... That's the reason I asked. It may be an issue that's come up in the interim. Anyway, I don't use FsUnit, since I find [Unquote](https://code.google.com/p/unquote) much better.